# How to get value from a an array individually in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i am trying to get the info of the following barcodes using a "get button" on them.

first, i scan the barcode then put it on a list. using this

```
Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        list.insert(
          0,
          barcode,
        );
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }
```

then, print the list using this:

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('${list[index]}'),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            getInfo();
                          },
                          child: Text("Get Info"),
                        ),
                      ],
```

see here, that the list is being generated with the "get info" in each result.
example is, i scanned two barcodes. 4912548796616 and 8998666001719 so they are inserted in the "list" List. when i print "list" my output is: I/flutter (16927): [4912548796616, 8998666001719], so that means our list creation is working, now my question is, how can i get them individually? i tried creating a "getInfo()" to print them but it only shows the latest barcode that i scanned. i hope you can help me. thanks!

this is my getInfo function, i am readying it up to have a query, to get the full info attached to the barcode. this is the one that is not working, as it only prints the latest barcode scanned.

```
Future<List> getInfo() async {
    print(this.barcode);
  }
```

Comment: You just need to reference the individual items in the list.  You could loop through them with a "for" loop ..... eg. for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) { print(list[i]); }

Comment: can u please give me a sample? im kinda lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks craig for the answer.. so i changed the

```
Future<List> getInfo() async {
    print(this.barcode);
  }
```

to this

```
Future<List> getInfo(index) async {
    print(list[index]);
  }
```